# Randomly guessing answers on a randomly generated test

Tags: probability, statistics, random

My question stems from answering questions (on a test) whose answer order was randomly chosen (not by a human, by a computer). I’m skeptical of something I just read:

> Your overall score will improve if you stick to choosing the same letter again and again when making blind guesses. This is because people are never truly random. If you’re making "random" blind guesses in a spread, you will almost certainly reduce your overall guesses odds, because your best attempt at random guessing cannot replicate computer-generated randomness.

This was found [here](https://blog.prepscholar.com/most-common-answer-on-act) which is a blog and may not be all that great of a source anyways, but that’s not my question.

They then went on to do a little example scenario in which they “randomly thought of a bunch of answers” to guess on the first 15 questions on an ACT from years ago, and also chose to answer C consistently on the same 15 questions. They then recorded how many they got correct while randomly guessing and how many they got correct while guessing C only. They got 2 correct with the “random” guessing and 4 correct while sticking to C.

Obviously running 1 example does not prove anything in statistics, after all anything could happen right?

My initial thought was that it wouldn’t matter if I chose different answers or the same one, I should always have a 25% chance of guessing correctly if there were 4 possible answers since the answer was chosen at random right?

*If a multiple choice test’s answer order is randomly generated (I mean randomly generated as in not by a human), how could it be possible that I have a less chance of getting correct answers over many questions while coming up with my own guesses rather than picking a letter and sticking to it?*

Comment: On rereading, I think your interpretation is correct.  If the test sequence is generated uniformly at random (each answer equally likely to be anything, independent of the other answers) then there is no advantage at all to guessing in one way or another.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a claim only about human behavior. They also asserted that your score will improve if you stick to a letter. Sticking to a letter is predictable, so are humans who randomly guess, why would my score likely be different? I still think my chances are the same even if I did have a computer of some sort to randomly generate an answer for me to choose. I feel like ‘predictable from random is random, and random from random is random’. I don’t see how the chances of guessing correctly change.

Comment: Ignore that comment, that was on your previous comment...

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that first comment because I had misread your post.

Comment: It depends on how random the sequence is. If we know that each answer appears 1/4 of the time, it sounds better to bet on the same answer if we want to get 1/4 of the score. By picking at random we may get a score below/above 1/4.

Comment: @Everstudent Yes, if each answer appears 1/4 of the time, that would make sense. Picking different numbers could add to the risk of missing the correct answer, but it could also add the risk of picking the correct answer one after another. But I’m asking the question about a test where answer(s) is/are generated independently of any previous answer(s).

Comment: Well, with a long enough sequence, each answer should appear around 1/4 of the time.

Comment: @Everstudent Even if each answer always did appear 1/4 of the time, shouldn’t my score appear to be around 1/4 correct no matter how I guess?